# Weird Javascript Bug in IE? for-loop string concatenation

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, for-loop

```
var pre = '<a href=someDirectoryPath';
var mid = '.aspx">';
var post = '</a>';
var trailHTML = '';
for(i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
    trailHTML = trailHTML + pre + getURL(trail[i]) + mid + trail[i] + post;
    if(i!=(trail.length-1)) {
    trailHTML += ' > ';
    }
}
document.write(trailHTML);
```

trail is an arraylist of valid pages, like so:

`['some name', 'another name','yet another name','name']`

getURL just takes that name and adds a `'-'` in between words, which is the page name. This has been tested and works. (for example, `getURL('some name')` returns `'some-name'`)

The problem is, when run in IE9 (untested in other browsers), when I write trailHTML to the page, I only get the last element in the array. Why is this?

Let me know if you need any clarification...

Comment: Personally, I would loop through the array to change each element of that array, so that you end up with an array of links. Then use `arr.join(" > ")` to put them together.

Comment: Much more elegant solution, thanks! As a side note, this helped me realize my larger error: I added `var i=0;` before the for loop, which fixed everything.

Comment: I would suggest to use ' &gt; ' instead of ' > ' since this could cause a weird behavior in IE, which is not very unlogical since html-tags use < and >

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function getURL(txt){
    return txt.replace(/ /g,"-");
}
var trail = ['some name', 'another name','yet another name','name'];

///////////////////////////////////////////////////

var pre = '<a href="someDirectoryPath/'; // changed
var mid = '.aspx">';
var post = '</a>';
var trailHTML = '';
for(i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
    trailHTML += pre + getURL(trail[i]) + mid + trail[i] + post;
    if(i<trail.length-1)trailHTML+=" &gt; " // changed
}
document.write(trailHTML);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntax error in your for-loop: The open "{" on the if does not have a matching "}".

I ran a small sample in IE9 and got all items in the array, not just the last item as you report. Here's what I ran:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function getURL(s){
    return s.replace(" ", "-");
}

var trail = ['some name', 'another name','yet another name','name'];
var pre = '<a href=someDirectoryPath';
var mid = '.aspx">';
var post = '</a>';
var trailHTML = '';
for(i=0;i<trail.length;i++) {
    trailHTML = trailHTML + pre + getURL(trail[i]) + mid + trail[i] + post;
    if(i!=(trail.length-1)) {
        trailHTML += " > ";
    }
}
trailHTML = trailHTML + getURL(trail[0]);
document.write(trailHTML);
</script>
```

The output looked like this:

> some name > another name > yet another name > namesome-name

Most likely your issue is caused by the syntax error, or in how the array is built/passed into your function.